# Azure Function cannot pull external site information

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-ssl-certificate or HTTP request with node JS and Azure function.

The function works locally so I think there is something wrong with the function network.

I'm just trying to get information about the SSL certificate.

Even the simple code below does the job, but again, locally works and on the function does not return anything.

var https = require('https');

```
 var options = {
     host: 'google.com',
     port: 443,
     method: 'GET'
 };

 const request = https.request(options, function (res) {
     context.log(res.connection.getPeerCertificate());
 });

 request.end();
```

I know that there are some limitations with the function networks, but I'm using other functions to send data to an external webhook with the same nodejs HTTP function and other npm packets without any problem and I get answers from the endpoint.

If there is a difference, can anyone explain why the request to hooks works and this should not work?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by wrapping the request with await before the request.